# I just noticed that the repo http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/

Tags: apt, package-management, google-chrome

For years, the way that Google Chrome was updated on Ubuntu was via the repository http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ As of now when I visit this URL I get a 404. Yet somehow Chrome appears to be at the latest version. Is Chrome being updated in some new way, perhaps by updating itself? Or is it blocking access via browser and wget?

Comment: I just test installed chrome on a new machine, and that is the repo it added. And it didn't error off when I did a `sudo apt update`. But I too get the 404 in a browser.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**
This is intentional measure to protect APT repository from bots. Google does not have index document on the `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/` or `http://dl.google.com` URLs.
The repository itself is working normally. See analysis below.

**Details**
In Wireshark session on my Ubuntu MATE 18.04.3 LTS box I see that `sudo apt-get update` downloads the `http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease` URL using `Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.6.14)` user-agent.

So you can hack this out by "visiting" the mentioned URLs using "wget" as follows:

> ```
> $ wget --spider --user-agent="Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.6.14)" http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:07:18--  http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/
> Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 108.177.14.91, 108.177.14.136, 108.177.14.190, ...
> Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|108.177.14.91|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
> Remote file does not exist -- broken link!!!
> ```

here 404 is confirmed.

But visiting the upper level `http://dl.google.com` URL gives redirect:

> ```
> $ wget --spider --user-agent="Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.6.14)" http://dl.google.com
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:09:34--  http://dl.google.com/
> Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 64.233.161.190, 64.233.161.93, 64.233.161.136, ...
> Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|64.233.161.190|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
> Location: http://www.google.com/chrome [following]
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:09:34--  http://www.google.com/chrome
> Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 64.233.163.105, 64.233.163.106, 64.233.163.99, ...
> Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|64.233.163.105|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
> Location: http://www.google.com/chrome/ [following]
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:09:34--  http://www.google.com/chrome/
> Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|64.233.163.105|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
> Location: https://www.google.com/chrome/ [following]
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:09:34--  https://www.google.com/chrome/
> Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|64.233.163.105|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
> Length: 301722 (295K) [text/html]
> Remote file exists and could contain further links,
> but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
> ```

From above HTTP conversation you can see the 302 redirect to https://www.google.com/chrome/ which allows humans do download Google Chrome from official web-page.

Also you can try to access `InRelease` file using the same user-agent directly as follows:

> ```
> $ wget --spider --user-agent="Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (1.6.14)" http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:12:10--  >http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease
> Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 64.233.161.190, 64.233.161.93, 64.233.161.136, ...
> Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|64.233.161.190|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
> Length: 1811 (1,8K) [application/octet-stream]
> Remote file exists.
> ```

or even access the same file with default user-agent:

> ```
> $ wget --spider http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease
> Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
> --2022-02-13 10:15:18--  >http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease
> Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 64.233.161.190, 64.233.161.93, 64.233.161.91, ...
> Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|64.233.161.190|:80... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
> Length: 1811 (1,8K) [application/octet-stream]
> Remote file exists.
> ```

So the 404 you get really means nothing for real use cases. APT needs other files which are normally available.